# Unicode character not visible while doing cat

Tags: linux, unicode, vi, cat, datastage

I have a CSV file generated by a windows system. The file is then moved to linux. The linux environment is NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server".VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)".ID="rhel".

When I use vi editor, all characters are visible. For example, one line is given :"Sarah--bitte nicht löschen".

But when i cat the file, i get something like "Sarah--bitte nicht l▒schen".

This file is consumed by datastage application and this unicode characters are coming as "?" in datastage. Since cat is not showing the character properly, I believe the issue is at the linux server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a encoding issue. Probably it is not UTF-8 encoded...

Answer (score 0):

`vi` reads the file using encoding according `fenc` setting and show the content using your locales setting ($LANG env). If `fenc` is different from `LANG`, `vi` can handle the translate.

But `cat` doesn't handle the translate, it always output the exact byte stream without any convert.

Your terminal will show the output content of both `vi` and `cat` using your *local PC locale* setting.